# java Runtime.exec to run interactive shell hangs

Tags: java, shell, io, runtime, ipc

I try to execute windows command `cmd` in java, feed it with commands and print the output or error on console. However, my attempt hangs after the banner message is printed. Here is the code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd");

        InputStream procOut = exec.getInputStream();
        InputStream procErrOut = exec.getErrorStream();
        OutputStream procIn = exec.getOutputStream();

        new StreamConsumer(procOut).run();
        new StreamConsumer(procErrOut).run();

        ByteArrayOutputStream byos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byos.write("ping 1.1.1.1".getBytes());
        byos.writeTo(procIn);
        byos.flush();
        procIn.flush();

        int ret = exec.waitFor();
        System.out.printf("Process exited with value %d", ret);
    }

    public static class StreamConsumer implements Runnable {

        private InputStream input;

        public StreamConsumer(InputStream input) {
            this.input = input;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the output

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
** program hangs **
```

Why does the program hang and no ping is executed (or printed)? I understand the streams must be consumed to avoid hanging (which I do in separate thread), but it still hangs. Has I misunderstood how the output stream is piped to interactive shell or what is the problem?

Comment: Just a guess, but the program could be doing the ping and then waiting forever for more input (since it's cmd).  You're not collecting any output.

Comment: May be related, but `StreamConsumer` is never used either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start threads to consume the outputs:

```
        new Thread(new StreamConsumer(procOut)).start();
        new Thread(new StreamConsumer(procErrOut)).start();
```

Comment: This solved the problem, but there is still issue, that prompt `C:\>` isn't printed until input is given. Why is that?

Comment: @TuomasToivonen probably because the outputs are consumed one line at a time